# How to mock the view in the MVC integration testing using JUnit and EasyMock

Tags: java, model-view-controller, junit, easymock

I would like to mock a view implementation of the `MVC design pattern`. I have implemented the `MVP`(another `MVC` variation), and would like to test if the certain methods in the view get called correctly by the controller when a state change happens on the model. The following shows the sequence of method calls on the `model`, `controller` and `view`.

Model:

```
model.setProperty("newProperty");
```

Controller:

```
@Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        for (View view : views) {
            view.modelPropertyChange(evt);
        }
    }
```

View:
This result to the view being called as like:

```
@Override
    public void modelPropertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        if ("Property".equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
            updateView();
        }
    }
```

Question: How do verify(using `EasyMock` in the `JUnit` test), the expected order of method(with valid argument(s)) execution? I expect `view.modelPropertyChange(evt)` to get called and the expect `view.isViewUpdated()` to return `true` on the `view` object. How do I say that in my JUnit test? Please help!

Answer (score 2):

```
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class ControllerTest {
  @Test
  public void updateView() {
    PropertyChangeEvent evt = new PropertyChangeEvent( ... );
    View mockView = EasyMock.createMock(View.class);
    mockView.modelPropertyChange(evt);
    EasyMock.replay(mockView);

    Controller controller = new Controller( ... );
    controller.propertyChange(mockView);
    EasyMock.verify(mockView);
  }
}
```

Note that the `Controller.propertyChange()` doesn't call `View.isViewUpdated()` so there is no need to mock `isViewUpdated`. You would test `isViewUpdated` in a test for the `View` class.

If `propertyChange` did call `isViewUpdated` then you would add the following call before `EasyMock.replay()`:

```
EasyMock.expect(mockView.isViewUpdated()).andReturn(true);
```

Note that `EasyMock.createMock()` does not enforce that the mocked methods be called in the order they were mocked. If you want the method order to be enforced, use `EasyMock.createStrictMock()`

Comment: I get an error when I run EasyMock.verify(mockView):"Expectation failure on verify..."

Comment: Usually you can tell from the stack trace what the problem is. The above code tells EasyMock to expect that "modelPropertyChange" will be called on the View with an event that is equal to "evt". If you get an exception in EasyMock.verify() that usually indicates that the method wasn't called.